# SQL obtener total de campo en query con join, sum y union

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum, union

Necesito obtener una tabla que cumpla con todos los siguientes parámetros y me sume la columna llamada "Monto total" ordenado por sucursales y por origenes, es decir que me de cuatro totales por sucursal y uno mayor por sucursal
Todos los resultados que obtengo son individuales. Entiendo que es por haber agrupado por todos los campos, pero cuando intento tocar dicho agrupamiento me devuelve solo errores
Ya intenté haber subquerys, hacer un tercer unión con una tabla para separar filas para resultados

```
SELECT *

FROM
(SELECT 
T1."PTICode" as "Sucursal",
T2."DocEntry" as "Documento",
T2."WhsCode" as "Almacen",
T1."DocNum" as "Numero",
T1."Indicator" as "Indicador",
T1."DocDate" as "Fecha", 
T6."GroupName" as "Nombre de grupo",
T1."CardCode" as "Codigo",
T1."CardName" as "Cliente", 
T1."U_COMIS" as "Comisionista",
T15."Name" as "Nombre Comisionista",
T2."ItemCode" as "Art�culo", 
T7."ItmsGrpNam" as "Grupo", 
T5."U_Linea" as "Linea",
T16."FirmName" as "Origen",
T2."Quantity" as "Cantidad", 
T2."LineTotal"*(100-IFNULL(T1."DiscPrcnt",0))/100 AS "Importe Neto",
T2."DiscPrcnt" as "Porcentaje",
T1."DiscPrcnt" as "Descuento",
(T2."GrossBuyPr" * T2."Quantity")  as "Costo",
((T2."LineTotal"*(100-IFNULL(T1."DiscPrcnt",0))/100)-(T2."GrossBuyPr" * T2."Quantity"))/(T2."LineTotal"*(100-IFNULL(T1."DiscPrcnt",0))/100)
as "Margen Bruto",

((T2."LineTotal"*(100-IFNULL(T1."DiscPrcnt",0))/100)- T2."GrossBuyPr")/T2."LineTotal"*(100-IFNULL(T1."DiscPrcnt",0))/100  AS "Margen",
T2."LineTotal"*((100-IFNULL(T1."DiscPrcnt",0))/100)*T2."Quantity" as "Monto Total",

T2."LineTotal"*((100-IFNULL(T1."DiscPrcnt",0))/100)*T2."Quantity" as "Total"

FROM 
 OINV T1
LEFT JOIN OCRD  T0 ON T0."CardCode" = T1."CardCode" 
LEFT JOIN INV1 T2 ON T1."DocEntry" = T2."DocEntry" 
LEFT JOIN OINV T3 ON T2."DocEntry" = T3."DocEntry" 
LEFT JOIN OSLP T4 ON T4."SlpCode" = T3."SlpCode" 
LEFT JOIN OITM T5 ON T5."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode" 
LEFT JOIN OCRG T6 ON T0."GroupCode" = T6."GroupCode"
LEFT JOIN OITB T7 ON  T5."ItmsGrpCod" = T7."ItmsGrpCod" 
LEFT JOIN "@COMISIONISTAS" T15 ON T1."U_COMIS"=T15."Code"
LEFT JOIN OMRC T16 ON T5."FirmCode"=T16."FirmCode"
WHERE T1."CANCELED" = 'N' AND T1."DocDate" >=[%0] AND   T1."DocDate" <=[%1]

UNION 
SELECT 
T8."PTICode" as "Sucursal",
T9."DocEntry",
T9."WhsCode" as "Almacen",
T8."DocNum",
T8."Indicator",
T8."DocDate", 
T13."GroupName" as "Grupo",
T8."CardCode",
T8."CardName",  
T8."U_COMIS",
T15."Name" as "Nombre Comisionista",
T9."ItemCode" as "Art�culo", 
T14."ItmsGrpNam", 
T12."U_Linea" as "Linea",
T16."FirmName" as "Origen",
-T9."Quantity" as "Cantidad", 
-T9."LineTotal"*(100-IFNULL(T8."DiscPrcnt",0))/100 AS "Importe Neto",
T9."DiscPrcnt", 
T8."DiscPrcnt",
-(T9."GrossBuyPr" * T9."Quantity") as "Costo",
-1*(((T9."LineTotal"*(100-IFNULL(T8."DiscPrcnt",0))/100)-(T9."GrossBuyPr" * T9."Quantity"))/(T9."LineTotal"*(100-IFNULL(T8."DiscPrcnt",0))/100))
as "Margen Bruto",

((-T9."LineTotal"*(100-IFNULL(T8."DiscPrcnt",0))/100)+ T9."GrossBuyPr")/-T9."LineTotal"*(100-IFNULL(T8."DiscPrcnt",0))/100  AS "Margen",
-T9."LineTotal"*((100-IFNULL(T9."DiscPrcnt",0))/100)*T9."Quantity" AS "Monto Total",

sum(T9."LineTotal"*((100-IFNULL(T9."DiscPrcnt",0))/100)*T9."Quantity") as "Total"

FROM 
ORIN T8 
LEFT JOIN OCRD  T0 ON T0."CardCode" = T8."CardCode" 
LEFT JOIN RIN1 T9 ON T8."DocEntry" = T9."DocEntry" 
LEFT JOIN ORIN T10 ON T9."DocEntry" = T10."DocEntry" 
LEFT JOIN OSLP T11 ON T11."SlpCode" = T10."SlpCode" 
LEFT JOIN OITM T12 ON T12."ItemCode" = T9."ItemCode" 
LEFT JOIN OCRG T13 ON T0."GroupCode" = T13."GroupCode"
LEFT JOIN OITB T14 ON  T12."ItmsGrpCod" = T14."ItmsGrpCod" 
LEFT JOIN "@COMISIONISTAS" T15 ON T8."U_COMIS"=T15."Code"
LEFT JOIN OMRC T16 ON T16."FirmCode"=T12."FirmCode"
WHERE T8."CANCELED" = 'N' 
AND T8."DocDate" >=[%0] AND   T8."DocDate" <=[%1]


GROUP BY 

T8."PTICode" ,
T9."DocEntry",
T9."WhsCode" ,
T8."DocNum",
T8."Indicator",
T8."DocDate", 
T13."GroupName" ,
T8."CardCode",
T8."CardName",  
T8."U_COMIS",
T15."Name" ,
T9."ItemCode" , 
T14."ItmsGrpNam", 
T12."U_Linea" ,
T16."FirmName" ,
T9."Quantity" , 
T9."LineTotal",
T9."DiscPrcnt", 
T8."DiscPrcnt",
T9."GrossBuyPr" ,
T9."Quantity"
 ) as tabla 

Order By "Sucursal" ASC, "Origen" ASC
```